# unknown token IDENT list error for IP address variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have defined variable in my .tfvars variable as

**variables.tfvars**

```
address_space = ["10.197.0.0/16"]
```

**build-windows.tf**

```
variable "address_space" {
  type = list
}
```

In build-windows.tf file I get the error as Unknow token ident list?

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, I even do not understand why terraform wants me to use the list instead of a string. When I use string I get an error in **terraform plan** stating that I have to use list.

Not going anywhere.

Please assist

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The type parameter is a string - try passing `"list"` into it.

```
variable "address_space" {
  type = "list"
}
```

Comment: Super! Worked :)

Comment: well that's def not whats in their docs, but it sure did work

Comment: As of v0.12, a variable type may be defined as an (unquoted) keyword: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html