# Unknown token IDENT aws_region

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have just run Terraform upgrade.  My code was updated but now it shows some errors.  The first was:

```
variable "s3_bucket_name" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "some_bucket_name",
    "other_bucket_name",
    ...
  ]
}
```

It doesn't like `list(string)`.  I went back to square one and redid the entire **[Getting Started](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform?track=getting-started#getting-started)** tutorial.  It said that I could either explicitly state `type = list` or I could implicitly state it by leaving out type and just using the [square brackets].

I saw here: [unknown token IDENT list error for IP address variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750472/unknown-token-ident-list-error-for-ip-address-variable) that I could use `"list"` (quotes) but I can't find any information on `list(string)`.

So I commented out my `list(string)` which moved the error along to the next part.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
```

The tutorial indicates that this is the correct way to create a region tag (there's actually part of the tutorial with that exact code).

**Can anyone help me to understand what `Unknown token IDENT` means as it's throughout my code but it's not helping me to understand what I should do to fix it.**

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using? That's HCL2 syntax that was introduced in Terraform 0.12

Comment: How can I check which version?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This error appears when you execute `terraform 0.12upgrade` and your code syntax is already in Terraform 0.12x or obviously a mix of syntax versions <= 0.11x and 0.12x. Also the Unknown token IDENT error can happen when your installed version on your local machine (or in the remote CI/CD server) is 0.11x and your code syntax is on 0.12x and you run a terraform command such as `terraform init`

```
variable "var1" {
  type = "list"
  ...
}
```

This a Terraform 0.11x [syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/variables.html) the alternative [12x](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html) is type = list(string)

To reproduce your error, I have a Terraform code 0.12x, I executed `terraform 0.12upgrade` then the `unknown token: IDENT` showed up!

In sum, I thought that your first code iteration is already in the correct syntax so there’s no need to upgrade. 
To avoid this kind of errors you can add a new `version.tf` file in your code with this content:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}
```

Upgrading tips:

1. Don’t mix the syntaxes in the same Terraform code, if so, downgrade manually your code to 0.11x
2. Put all your Terraform code syntax in 0.11x
3. Then run: terraform 0.12upgrade

Comment: Welcome to the community, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to know which version of Terraform I am running?  Sorry if that is a silly question, I'm really new to this.

Comment: `$ terraform version` :
Prints the Terraform version

Answer (score 2):

Terraform Version: `0.11.14`

I had to fix the code as well.

Changed

`data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.main_vpc_id`

to

`"${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.main_vpc_id}"`