# Terraform Serverless Applications with AWS Lambda and API Gateway unknown token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm learning terraform, and one of the well [written tutorials on hashicorp](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway) has given me some problems towards the end.

I have a file defining my lambda, and its relationship to an API Gateway.  The connections to the API Gateway haven't been tested, since I can't seem to get the API Gateway to deploy.

**lambda.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
    shared_credentials_file = "/home/camelType/.aws/credentials"
    profile = "default" 
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
    function_name = "ServerlessExample"

   # The bucket name as created earlier with "aws s3api create-bucket"
    s3_bucket = "camelType-serverless-example"
    s3_key    = "v1.0.0/example.zip"

   # "main" is the filename within the zip file (main.js) and "handler"
   # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
   # exported in that file.
    handler = "main.handler"
    runtime = "nodejs12.x"

    role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_exec_role.arn}"
}



resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec_role" {
    name = "lambda_exec_role"
    assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

//Haven't tested below here

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id
   path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
   http_method   = "ANY"
   authorization = "NONE"
}
```

I've deployed the lambda alone, and it worked as expected.

However, when I went to the next step, and added the api gateway, I get a parsing error for the `aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id`.  I assumed that the `example.id` was a reference to the `aws_api_gateway_rest_api` resource above, so the `example.id` name is correct, but that's the line it's having trouble parsing.

**api_gateway.tf**

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
    name        = "ServerlessExample"
    description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
    //issue here
    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.resource_id
    http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.http_method

    integration_http_method = "POST"
    type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
    uri                     = aws_lambda_function.example.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy_root" {
    rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id
    http_method   = "ANY"
    authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.resource_id
    http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method 

    integration_http_method = "POST"
    type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
    uri                     = aws_lambda_function.example.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
    depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root,
   ]

    rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    stage_name  = "test"
}
```

I've gone through a few of their tutorials, and this is the first one I've had issues with.  I'm sure it's my error, but I've gone over it several times, and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The copy paste of the error message is `Error: Error parsing /home/camelType/api_gateway.tf: At 7:18: Unknown token: 7:18 IDENT aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id`

Comment: Can you post exact error message?

Comment: Yes, error message posted at end.  Also here `Error: Error parsing /home/camelType/api_gateway.tf: At 7:18: Unknown token: 7:18 IDENT aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id`

Comment: What terraform version are you using? There are some similar issues indicating that you might be using old version which does no support new syntax?

Comment: @Marcin That was it.  I haven't gotten used to snaps yet, and it installed v0.11.11.  I thought I had already upgraded, but it was still using the snap.  What a ridiculous mistake.  Thanks!  I'm now on v0.13.0, and now i'm getting a much more manageable `Error creating API Gateway: AccessDeniedException` which is much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer with more info for future references :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **old version of terraform** (v0.11.11), while using syntax from newer version in the config files.

Similar issues have been reported:

- [Unknown token: 2:23 IDENT max](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-vpc/issues/267)
- [Unknown token IDENT aws_region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471513/unknown-token-ident-aws-region)

The **solution** was to upgrade terraform.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!  One day I'll get used to snaps......or leave Ubuntu....We'll see.